# I am trying to code a game but I ran into an issue. My print commands do not work, I am sure I wrote it wrong, but I cant find the problem

Tags: assembly, x86

In the proc section, before the start but in the code segment I wrote 2 procs, 'proc CheckYInput' and proc 'CheckXInput', which are supposed to find out which button I pressed, compare it to the numbered cell and if it is one of the 8 random cell, print over it.
It's basically a very bad 'mine sweeper'

```
 IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG


; random 
Clock equ es:6Ch


; after change 



;for opening screen
HTS DB "mine sweeper"
PAKTC DB "[Press space to continue]"


empty DB " "

    xStart dw 1  ; x coordinate of line start

    yStart dw 0 ; y coordinate of line start

    length1 dw 1278 ; length1 of line1
 
    yStart2 dw 25  ; y coordinate of line2 start
    
    yStart3 dw 50  ; y coordinate of line3 start
  
    yStart4 dw 75 ; y coordinate of line4 start

    yStart5 dw 100 ; y coordinate of line5 start

    yStart6 dw  125 ; y coordinate of line6 start

    yStart7 dw 150  ; y coordinate of line7 start

    yStart8 dw 175  ; y coordinate of line8 start
    
    ;for random

Random1X db (?)
Random2X db (?)
Random3X db (?)
Random4X db (?)
Random5X db (?)
Random6X db (?)
Random7X db (?)
Random8X db (?)
Random1Y db (?)
Random2Y db (?)
Random3Y db (?)
Random4Y db (?)
Random5Y db (?)
Random6Y db (?) 
Random7Y db (?)
Random8Y db (?) 

CODESEG

;======================================
;=============cursor mode==============
;======================================



proc ScreenClear 
    mov ax,0600h    
    mov bh,99h    ;color of backround 
    mov cx,0000h    ;start position
    mov dx,184fh    ;end position 
    int 10h        ;screenprint 
    
    
    ret
endp ScreenClear    


proc modulo


    mov ax, 40h
    mov es, ax
    mov cx, 1
    mov bx, 0

    mov ax, [Clock] ;read timer counter
    mov ah, [byte cs:bx] ;read one byte from memory
    xor al, ah ;xor memory and counter
    and al, 00000101b ;leave result between 0-7
    
ret 
endp modulo 

proc modulo2

    mov ax, 40h
    mov es, ax
    mov cx, 1
    mov bx, 0

    mov ax, [Clock] ;read timer counter
    mov ah, [byte cs:bx] ;read one byte from memory
    xor al, ah ;xor memory and counter
    and al, 00000100b ;leave result between 0-4
ret 
endp modulo2

proc CheckXInput
IdkLOOP:
    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    cmp al,31h
    je RandomLoopX
    cmp al,32h
    je RandomLoopX
    cmp al,33h 
    je RandomLoopX
    cmp al,34h 
    je RandomLoopX
    cmp al,35h
    je RandomLoopX
    cmp al,36h
    je RandomLoopX
    cmp al,37h
    je RandomLoopX
    cmp al,38h
    je RandomLoopX
    jmp IdkLOOP; loops untill i hit left click 
    
    
RandomLoopX: ; starts a loop that checks each Y cordinate 
    sub al,31h
    cmp al,[Random1X]
    je RandomLOOPX2
    
    cmp al,[Random2X]
    je RandomLoopX2
    
    cmp al,[Random3X]
    je RandomLoopX2
    
    cmp al,[Random4X]
    je RandomLoopX2
    
    cmp al,[Random5X]
    je RandomLoopX2
    
    cmp al,[Random6X]
    je RandomLoopX2
    
    cmp al,[Random7X]
    je RandomLoopX2
    
    cmp al,[Random8X]
    je RandomLoopX2
    
    jmp IdkLOOP
    
RandomLoopX2:
    inc al
    dec al
    mov bl, 64
    mul bl ; mul 64 by the number of the cell and stores the answer in bx
    mov ax,bx ; moves the number of the cell in pixels to ax
    add bx,64 ; the end of the cell in pixels 
    
    jmp RandomLoopX3
RandomLoopX3:
    mov bh,55h    ;color of backround 
    mov dx,ax
    dec bx
    int 10h       ;screenprint
    cmp bx,ax
    ja RandomLoopX3
    
ret 
    endp CheckXInput
    
    
    
    proc CheckYInput 
IdkLOOP2:
    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    cmp al,31h
    je RandomLoopY
    cmp al,32h
    je RandomLoopY
    cmp al,33h 
    je RandomLoopY
    cmp al,34h 
    je RandomLoopY
    cmp al,35h
    je RandomLoopY
    jmp IdkLOOP2
    
    RandomLoopY: ; starts a loop that checks each Y cordinate 
    sub al,31h
    cmp al,[Random1Y]
    je RandomLOOPY2
    
    cmp al,[Random2Y]
    je RandomLoopY2
    
    cmp al,[Random3Y]
    je RandomLoopY2
    
    cmp al,[Random4Y]
    je RandomLoopY2
    
    cmp al,[Random5Y]
    je RandomLoopY2
    
    cmp al,[Random6Y]
    je RandomLoopY2
    
    cmp al,[Random7Y]
    je RandomLoopY2
    
    cmp al,[Random8Y]
    je RandomLoopY2
    
    jmp IdkLOOP2
    
    
RandomLoopY2: ; starts a loop that checks each x cordinate
    mov cl,al 
    mov bl, 25
    mul bl
    mov ax,bx
    add bx,25
    jmp RamdomLoopY3
RamdomLoopY3:
    mov bh,55h    ;color of backround 
    mov dx,ax ; start 
    dec bx
    int 10h       ;screenprint
    cmp bx,ax ;checks if reached end, if not it will keep printing 
    ja RamdomLoopY3
ret 
    endp CheckYInput
    
proc callmodulo 
    call modulo 
mov [Random1X],al
call modulo
mov [Random2X],al
call modulo
mov [Random3X],al
call modulo
mov [Random4X],al
call modulo
mov [Random5X],al
call modulo
mov [Random6X],al
call modulo
mov [Random7X],al
call modulo
mov [Random8X],al

ret
endp callmodulo

proc callmodulo2
call modulo2
mov [Random1Y],al
call modulo2
mov [Random2Y],al
call modulo2
mov [Random3Y],al
call modulo2
mov [Random4Y],al
call modulo2
mov [Random5Y],al
call modulo2
mov [Random6Y],al
call modulo2
mov [Random7Y],al
call modulo2
mov [Random8Y],al


ret

endp callmodulo2
    
    
;===================================
;============start=================
;===================================


start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    ; Graphic mode
    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h
    

    
    
    ;first text for first screen 
    mov al, 1 ;color 
    mov bh, 0 
    mov bl, 15 ;brightness 
    mov cx, 12 ;PAKTC1end - offset PAKTC ; calculate message number of letters plus spaces, ect...  
    mov dl, 11  ;position start X
    mov dh, 10 ;position start Y 
    push ds 
    pop es
    mov bp, offset HTS
    mov ah, 13h ;graphic font 
    int 10h ; print

    
    ;second text for first screen
    mov al, 1 ; color 
    mov bh, 27 
    mov bl, 15 ; brightness 
    mov cx, 26 ;PAKTC1end - offset PAKTC ; calculate message number of letters plus spaces, ect... 
    mov dl, 7 ; position start X
    mov dh, 15 ; position start Y 
    push ds
    pop es
    mov bp, offset PAKTC
    mov ah, 13h
    int 10h
    
    
;space press
checkTitleSpace: 
    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    cmp al, 20h ;space ascii
    jne checkTitleSpace
    
    call ScreenClear ; calls the proc ScreenClear

    


;========================================
;=============after opening==============
;========================================


    ;useless title 
    ;space press
    Draw2:
    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h 
    cmp al, 20h ;space ascii 
    jne Draw2 
    ;first draw

    mov ah,0h
    mov al,13h
    int 10h

;The above three lines just switch to 320x200 256-color VGA.
    mov ax, 0a000h
    mov es, ax  
    mov bx, 0 
loopClear:
    mov [byte ptr es:bx], 11h
    inc bx
    cmp bx, 320 * 200
    jb loopClear
    
;=============================================  
;==============lines start here===============
;=============================================  

    mov cx, [xStart]
    add cx, [length1]


   ; loop from (xStart+length1) to xStart to draw a horizontal line

    LoopStart: 

       ; draw a pixel
        mov al, 50 ; color
        mov dx, [yStart]      
        mov ah, 0ch  ; set sub function value in ah to draw a pixel       
        int 10h ; and invoke the interrupt                                  
        dec cx  ; decrement the x coord      
        cmp cx, [xStart]  ; test to see if x coord has reached start value   
    jae LoopStart ; continue loop if cx >= xStart
            
    mov dx, [ystart]
    add dx, [length1]

   ; loop from (ystart+length1) to ystart and add length1

    LoopStart2:
       ; draw a pixel
       ; set color in al, x in cx, y in dx
        mov al,50  ;color
        mov cx, [xStart] 
        mov ah, 0ch  
        int 10h
        dec dx  ; decrement the y coord
        cmp dx, [yStart] ; test to see if y coord has reached start value
  
    jne LoopStart2 ; continue loop if dx >= yStart  

    mov cx, [xStart]
    add cx, [length1]
    LoopStart3:
        mov al, 50 ;color 
        mov dx, [yStart2]   
        mov ah, 0ch  
        int 10h 
        dec cx ; decrement the y coord
        cmp cx, [xStart] ; test to see if y coord has reached start value       
    jne LoopStart3
    
    mov cx, [xStart]
    add cx, [length1]
    LoopStart4:
        mov al, 50 ;color 
        mov dx, [yStart3]   
        mov ah, 0ch  
        int 10h 
        dec cx ; decrement the y coord
        cmp cx, [xStart] ; test to see if y coord has reached start value       
    jne LoopStart4
    
    

    mov cx, [xStart]
    add cx, [length1]
    LoopStart5:
        mov al, 50 ;color 
        mov dx, [yStart4]   
        mov ah, 0ch  
        int 10h 
        dec cx ; decrement the y coord
        cmp cx, [xStart] ; test to see if y coord has reached start value       
    jne LoopStart5
    

    mov cx, [xStart]
    add cx, [length1]
    LoopStart6:
        mov al, 50 ;color 
        mov dx, [yStart5]   
        mov ah, 0ch  
        int 10h 
        dec cx ; decrement the y coord
        cmp cx, [xStart] ; test to see if y coord has reached start value       
    jne LoopStart6
    


    mov cx, [xStart]
    add cx, [length1]
    LoopStart7:
        mov al, 50 ;color 
        mov dx, [yStart6]   
        mov ah, 0ch  
        int 10h 
        dec cx ; decrement the y coord
        cmp cx, [xStart] ; test to see if y coord has reached start value       
    jne LoopStart7
    

    mov cx, [xStart]
    add cx, [length1]
    LoopStart8:
        mov al, 50 ;color 
        mov dx, [yStart7]   
        mov ah, 0ch  
        int 10h 
        dec cx ; decrement the y coord
        cmp cx, [xStart] ; test to see if y coord has reached start value       
    jne LoopStart8
    



    mov cx, [xStart]
    add cx, [length1]
    LoopStart9:
        mov al, 50 ;color 
        mov dx, [yStart8]   
        mov ah, 0ch  
        int 10h 
        dec cx ; decrement the y coord
        cmp cx, [xStart] ; test to see if y coord has reached start value       
    jne LoopStart9
    


;===================================================
;========lines end here (thank god)=================
;===================================================

;==============================
;=========for random===========
;==============================



call callmodulo
call callmodulo2
call CheckXInput
call CheckYInput







    

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

This is the code, I know I know it's bad. But please help me figure out the problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> length1 dw 1278 ; length1 of line1
> ```

This value of 1278 is much too big! In the program you are adding this value to what are X and Y coordinates for a screen that is limited to 320 pixels horizontally and 200 pixels vertically.

> ```
> mov dx,184fh    ;end position
> ```

Maybe you copied this *ScreenClear* code from somewhere else, but for the screen 13h that you use the biggest column index is 39 (27h). The correct code is:

```
mov dx, 1827h
```

The *CheckYInput* routine forgets to check the input of <kbd>6</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd>, and <kbd>8</kbd>.

In *CheckXInput* and in *CheckYInput* you have the following errors:

> ```
> mov bl, 64
> mul bl ; mul 64 by the number of the cell and stores the answer in bx
> mov ax,bx ; moves the number of the cell in pixels to ax
> ```

The 3rd instruction here immediately overwrites the result (in `AX`) of the multiplication.

And a few lines further down you have

> ```
> int 10h       ;screenprint
> ```

but there's no BIOS function number to work with!

Comment: Thank you. 
the length part is correct, since if I do make it lower it will not have enough for the pixel in  every column, as I tried smaller values.
I didn't check for the numbers 6,7, and 8 in the Y because there isn't a place for it in the table.
I didn't notice I overwrote in the multiplication, so thank you for that.
Also. I do not know what is BIOS is, Though I will read about it. 
Nonetheless, thank you very much!